# NFS randomly mounts wrong server

Tags: ubuntu, nfs

I have run into a problem with NFS which has me baffled. I can't even come up with a plausible explanation for it. I have ten machines:

slave1 (10.0.0.10) - slave10 (10.0.0.20)

Each one runs NFS server and exports a directory.

I mount the directories as usual:

```
sudo mount 10.0.0.11:/var/export /mnt/slave/1/ -o soft
sudo mount 10.0.0.12:/var/export /mnt/slave/2/ -o soft
...
sudo mount 10.0.0.20:/var/export /mnt/slave/10/ -o soft
```

At this point the mounts look like this:

```
10.0.0.11:/var/export on /mnt/slaves/1 type nfs (rw,soft,vers=4,addr=10.0.0.11,clientaddr=10.3.3.212)
10.0.0.12:/var/export on /mnt/slaves/2 type nfs (rw,soft,vers=4,addr=10.0.0.12,clientaddr=10.3.3.212)
10.0.0.13:/var/export on /mnt/slaves/3 type nfs (rw,soft,vers=4,addr=10.0.0.13,clientaddr=10.3.3.212)
10.0.0.14:/var/export on /mnt/slaves/4 type nfs (rw,soft,vers=4,addr=10.0.0.14,clientaddr=10.3.3.212)
10.0.0.15:/var/export on /mnt/slaves/5 type nfs (rw,soft,vers=4,addr=10.0.0.15,clientaddr=10.3.3.212)
10.0.0.16:/var/export on /mnt/slaves/6 type nfs (rw,soft,vers=4,addr=10.0.0.16,clientaddr=10.3.3.212)
10.0.0.17:/var/export on /mnt/slaves/7 type nfs (rw,soft,vers=4,addr=10.0.0.17,clientaddr=10.3.3.212)
10.0.0.18:/var/export on /mnt/slaves/8 type nfs (rw,soft,vers=4,addr=10.0.0.18,clientaddr=10.3.3.212)
10.0.0.19:/var/export on /mnt/slaves/9 type nfs (rw,soft,vers=4,addr=10.0.0.19,clientaddr=10.3.3.212)
10.0.0.20:/var/export on /mnt/slaves/10 type nfs (rw,soft,vers=4,addr=10.0.0.20,clientaddr=10.3.3.212)
```

Now, for what has me baffled. Some of these mounts are, randomly, pointing at the wrong server!

For example, the files /mnt/slaves/2 may be from slave5 (10.0.0.15). Or perhaps from slave9. Or if I am lucky from slave2. Unmounting and mounting again, using exactly the same line causes the mount to randomly point at another slave. By remounting enough times (and after each check if I got the right slave) I can get the mounts right, but it is a big annoyance.

This problem is showing up using ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

Some info:

- It's not DNS. We are not using DNS.
- It's not an IP/Mac address conflict. All other prototocols (SSH, HTTP etc) goes to the right
  slave.
- I can't see anything in the logs, as far as I can tell the master thinks it communicates with the right slave.
- Using wireshark I see some traffic to the right slave. The master sends the SETCLIENTID command, so it initiates communication. After that communication just stops. No SETCLIENTID_CONFIRM is sent.

So at this point I wonder:

- Is this some kind of known bug?
- Is there a workaround for it?

I have managed to reproduce the same behavior on two different Ubuntu systems setup at different times, so it is not isolated to a single server.

Comment: When the filesystem from the wrong NFS server is mounted, is this reflected in the output of the `mount` command? I think from what you say that mount table always looks correct even when filesystems are coming from wrong servers.

Comment: Is there anything _significant_ (for some meaning of significant) between NFS client and NFS servers that might mess up the NFS traffic? Protocol aware firewall?

Comment: Do the logs on the NFS servers reflect the mounts that are happening or what you ask for? For example if slaves/2 comes from slave5 is the mount request logged on 2 or 5?

Comment: @PaulHaldane: The Mount output always looks correct. The incorrect servers are not reflected in the output from mount. There is no firewall in between.

Comment: @PaulHaldane As far as I can see there is nothing logged when mounting from one of the slaves. Where should NFS log this?

Comment: I'm just going on how our CentOS 5.x NFS servers behave - they log all mount/umount requests to /var/log/messages. It may be that Ubuntu's mountd is quieter. I can't see how mount request (and so log) could be happening anywhere else but the 'wrong' server.

Comment: Can you get some wireshark traces during the mount? I'd be interested to see if there's any traffic to the client from any NFS server other than the one you're trying to mount.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: I am not on the site with the systems at the moment, so it will take a couple of weeks before I can begin debugging that again. But the pattern as far as I could tell was that the server initiated communication with the right server, and then suddenly broke off and setup the connection with another server.

Comment: Since you're running NFSv4, can you check whether the `/etc/exports` on the servers have `refer` directives that point to other servers?

Comment: Do you have any bind mounts or autofs mounts?   Have you tried un-mounting everything, manually setting an fsid to the export of each server, restarting nfs, remounting?  Not sure what else I would try.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick : Nothing extra in the /etc/exports. Just the address and directory.

Comment: @Aaron : The FSID may be an idea. The servers are cloned, so maybe the UUID of the filesystem is identical and this causes the problems. I will see if I can set it up and test providing an FSID and see if that helps.